# How can I set a StackPanels margins individually?

Tags: c#, wpf, margin, code-behind, stackpanel

I can set the margin of a stackpanel in code-behind like this:

```
StackPanel sp2 = new StackPanel();
sp2.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(5);
```

**But how can I set each individually**, both of these don't work:

*PSEUDO-CODE:*

```
sp2.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness("5 0 0 0");
sp2.Margin.Left = new System.Windows.Thickness(5);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
sp2.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness{ Left = 5 };
```

Answer (score 6):

Margin is of type Thickness which is a structure.

The parsing of "5 0 0 0" is a XAML thing, its not something that Thickness constructor handles.

Use

```
sp2.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(5,0,0,0);
```

since Thickness is a structure this should also work, leaving the other margin values unmodified:-

```
sp2.Margin.Left = 5;
```

Comment: Does your last line actually leave the rest unmodified? [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316649/2550406) claims otherwise