# how to change a collection of background images without specifying uri source or path in c# for windows store app

Tags: c#

I have a `collectionViewSource` with my data that has theme elements and images that I'm trying to display at runtime in a windows store app. So how can I change my background color using my own data Context.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285018/equivalent-of-css-in-xaml/13287730#13287730

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that's not what i was looking for ,i just want to know how to put a collection list of images into a bitmapimage class