# How to set a left margin only in Xamarin Forms XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

This question is the same as [How to set a top margin only in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316405/how-to-set-a-top-margin-only-in-xaml) but regarding Xamarin instead of WPF.

How can I set an individual margin on a view from XAML?

The linked Q&A indicates that the default implementation always sets all unspecified Margins to 0, even from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create an [AttachedProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties):

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace Sample.Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows setting Top,Left,Right,Bottom Margin independently from each other.
    /// The default implementation does not allow that, even from code. This
    /// attached property remembers the previously set margins and only modifies what you intend to modify.
    /// </summary>
    public static class Margin
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty LeftProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
            propertyName: "Left",
            returnType: typeof(double),
            declaringType: typeof(Margin),
            propertyChanged: LeftPropertyChanged,
            defaultValue: 0.0d);

        private static void LeftPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            SetLeft(bindable, (double)newValue);
        }

        public static void SetLeft(BindableObject element, double value)
        {
            var view = element as View;
            if (view != null)
            {
                Thickness currentMargin = (Xamarin.Forms.Thickness)view.GetValue(View.MarginProperty);

                view.Margin = new Thickness(value, currentMargin.Top, currentMargin.Right, currentMargin.Bottom);
            }
        }

        public static double GetLeft(BindableObject element)
        {
            View view = element as View;
            if (view != null)
            {
                Thickness margin = (Xamarin.Forms.Thickness)view.GetValue(View.MarginProperty);
                return margin.Left;
            }
            return (double)LeftProperty.DefaultValue;
        }

    }
}
```

Declare this in the same way for `Bottom`, `Top`, and `Right`. Then use it in XAML like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         xmlns:utils="using:Sample.Utils"
         x:Class="Sample.MyContentPage">
<StackLayout
   Orientation="Vertical"
   utils:Margin.Left="{StaticResource InnerPageContentMarginLeft}">
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

---

Sources:
* https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/66026/use-attached-bindable-property-in-xaml
* https://stackoverflow.com/a/32408461/2550406

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something, it's just a matter of specifying the Margin as follows:

```
<Label
    Margin = "0,20,0,0"
    Text = "Hello World!" />
```

The *Margin* is specified as *left*, *top*, *right*, *bottom* values.

Comment: This only works if you already know all the Margins you want to set. If you would like to overwrite only one of them, this does not work - instead it sets all others to 0

Comment: That's what I was missing! Fair comment. My solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a valueConverter where you can send a value to converter through binding and return a Thickness object.
Somewhat like

`Margin ={{Binding Marginleft, Converter={StaticResource stringToThicknessConverter}}`

where you pass a string and get back a thickness object like
  `new thickness(0,marginleft,0,0)`.

Also you could directly bind to a thickness type object in viewModel but that's a bad practice as it would create a View dependency in ViewModel  which defeats the purpose of MVVM